# Is it possible to set a specific color as a background for your app instead of using a background image?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio, background

As the title says, is it possible to set a specific color as a background for your app instead of using a background image on android studio? I've been seeking for sources through googling if its possible but I still haven't found anything near to my needs yet.

Comment: @Vishal Patoliya, I'm sorry but I find my question clear, and doesn't need a code to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme from styles.xml add this

```
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
```

This way, all your activities will have the background set to white. (all the activities with this theme)

Or just use in all your activities

```
android:background="@color/white"
```

You can write anything you want instead of @color/white.

Comment: When I try to use

android:background="@color/white",

there is an error shows which says that there is a rendering problems. In addition to that, it also says that it failed to convert @color/red into a drawable.

Comment: You get the error in the designer, or while running the app?

Comment: I suppose you do mean by the designer is the mobile preview, and yes, I get the error in the designer.

Comment: You need to put #FFFFFF in your color resource.

Comment: @Stanojkovic is there a link you could provide me as a reference of that type of colors?

Comment: This helped answered has helped with the help of @Stanojkovic, thanks lads!

Answer (score 0):

In your styles.xml
use 
 "@color/specific_color" as windows background

eg.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

 <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/specific_color</item></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**step 1: you can give your activity background color by background attributes.**

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">    

       // Your Design

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it and its actually working, but the problem is I don't know the hex mode of the colors I want to use. Would you mind giving me a link as a reference? And also I tried to use 'red' / 'blue' replacing the hex mode, but unfortunately it didn't work and gave me an error which says that it failed to convert red/blue into a drawable.

Comment: Colors are in RGB format
it means if color code is #FFFFFF.than
first FF is for Red.
second and third for Green and
last two FF is for Blue color of combination.

Comment: This comment above also has helped, thanks @Vishal Patoliya!

Answer (score 0):

Yes most definitely it is possible. Just do the following:

Define the custom color in the **colors.xml** resource file like

```
<color name="background">#111111</color>
```

Then use this defines color value for any background attribute.

- For all backgrounds across the app define the background in

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--This is for only the window background-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>
```

- For setting background of indivial views, set the `background` attribute of the view to that color

  android:background="@color/background"

This is a very helpful link for reference to colors for Android Material Design. Check it out.

[Color-Style-Google design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette)